# Can't grab all the pdf links within a table from a webpage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to scrape different ***`pdf`*** links generated upon clicking on the different numbers, as in `110015710`, `110015670` etc located within a table from a webpage.

***[Site link](https://www.iec.co.il/suppliers/pages/tenderslist.aspx?FreeText=&PubDate=1)***

My script can click on those links, reveal the `pdf` files but parse only 5 of them out of many.

***How can I get them all?***

I've tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "replace_with_above_link"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(link)

[driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",item) for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"tr.Iec")))]
for elem in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".IecAttachments li a[href$='.pdf']"))):
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you click the element it will doing XHR to request for pdf links, add delay after every click.

```
for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"tr.Iec"))):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",item)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use explicit wait instead of hardcoded delay in such cases @ewwink?

Comment: yes you can wait until element `tr.IecExtended ul` located, this element is next sibling for `tr.Iec`